# pygame.key.get_pressed() appears to be frozen

Tags: python, input, pygame

I'm trying to make a menu system for my game where you start at the main menu, then you can go to the tutorial by pressing space, then to the game by pressing space again. The problem is I needed to make sure the player has let go of space before letting them exit the tutorial but pygame.key.get_pressed() reports that the same keys that were being pressed when you exited the menu are still being pressed even if they aren't. Here's my code.

```
def menu(normal=True):
    global keys
    while True:
        pygame.time.wait(33)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            return True
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False

#Main menu
displayMenuText(0)
menu()

#Tutorial
displayMenuText(1)
while pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    pygame.time.wait(33)
menu()
```

The menu() function returning a boolean value is used elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `pygame.KEYUP` event to check for key press.

```
events = pygame.event.get()
for event in events:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
       if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
           return True
```

Comment: To be complete in the answer, it probably should add that the reason `pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]` returns `True` even after the user has released the key is because it's not updated until you call one of the event functions `pygame.event.get`, `pygame.event.poll`, `pygame.event.pump` or `pygame.event.clear`

Comment: Further to @TedKleinBergman s comment: from the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) for `pygame.event.pump()`: "For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system. If you are not using other event functions in your game, you should call pygame.event.pump() to allow pygame to handle internal actions". If you do not do this or have an event loop, pygame will hang. So you can replace the event loop in this answer with `pygame.event.pump()`.